# How can I convert a date string into another format using MapStruct?

Tags: date, format, mapstruct

I am using MapStruct to map values from a source to a target class. Both classes shall have a date property but with different dateformats.
How can I convert the dateformat whilst mapping the properties using MapStruct?

Date format from source class: 2018-05-18T18:43:33.623+0200

Date format of target class: 2018-05-18

Answer (score 5):

I presume your date properties are of `String` type.

You can create a custom qualified method for that and pick that method for mapping your source and target. Have a look at [Mapping method selection based on qualifiers](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#selection-based-on-qualifiers)

It can look like:

```java
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "dateProperty", source = "dateProperty", qualifiedBy = WithTimezoneToLocalDate.class)
    Target map(Source source);

    @WithTimezoneToLocalDate
    default String timezoneToLocalDate(String source) {
        // Do your conversion here
    }

}


import org.mapstruct.Qualifier;

@Qualifier
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
public @interface WithTimezoneToLocalDate {
}
```

Comment: Great answer. @Target annotation should be fixed, though:
`@Target(ElementType.METHOD)`

Answer (score 2):

### Processing a source object / object-field

Assuming that the source is a String, first it must be parsed into a "date" object, then you can convert it into any format you like.

The others solution is ok, you can also use an "expression", when data must be treated before being sent to the target object.

It allows you to use also other languages (eg. Javascript), but let's use Java now:

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface PaymentMethodMapper extends EntityMapper<PaymentMethodDTO, PaymentMethod> {

    @Mapping(source = "creditCard.id", target = "creditCardId")
     // ...
    @Mapping(target = "expireDate", expression = "java(creditCardExpire(paymentMethod.getCreditCard()))")
    PaymentMethodDTO toDto(PaymentMethod paymentMethod);


    default String creditCardExpire(CreditCard cc) {
        LocalDate expDate = LocalDate.of(cc.getExpirationYear(), cc.getExpirationMonth(), 1);
        return  expDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/yy"));
    }

     // ...
}
```

Basically you specify the language of the expression (java) and between parenthesis there's the function call, which is defined later in the same interface. You can pass to it a single value, or a whole object, depending on what you need to do.

In this case I've got `...toDto(PaymentMethod paymentMethod)`, paymentMethod is the source object that I decided to feed into the function.

### Parsing a String with a specific format into a "date" object

Your date is in [ISO format](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.ISO.html) which is really good: `2018-05-18T18:43:33.623+0200`

**First, tell Java how to parse the input:**

`DateTimeFormatter dtFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME;`

**Then, feed the source string into the formatter**

`TemporalAccessor t = dtFormatter.parse("2018-05-18T18:43:33.623+0200");`

Now it's up to you, depending on the need, to choose the final output object:

```
// Instant: keep a reference on the timeline
Instant momentInTime = Instant.from(t);


// LocalDateTime: just date & time information, with no reference to other 
events on the timeline
LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.from(t);


// LocalDate - finally, the date that you requested:
LocalDate d = LocalDate.from(t);

System.out.println("Your date: " + d.toString());
```

### From a date object back to a formatted String

Sometimes we need to go back from date to string, with a certain format.

First, give a look at the standard formats defined in [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class, there's a lot of useful stuff, if yours is not available, you can build one yourself (see "Patterns for Formatting and Parsing" in the doc).

```
 LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
 DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy MM dd");
 String text = date.format(formatter);
```

Output: `2021 01 02`

---

I hope that the answer is not gone to far...!

[java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) is very useful when working with date/time, there are many answers on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-time) explaning the best object to use for each job (especially when dealing with timezones!)

Happy Coding! ;)